# IOS App Store Connect not showing new build status

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have created a new IOS App build in XCode and have uploaded it to App Store Connect. I can see the build under the activity tab but it does not show a status. I have added a screen shot here. Is this normal because I would like to create a new version of my app from here?
[image]

Comment: Its fine, the status you are talking about is "App Store Status" it will show when this build is used for app submissions

Comment: Thanks @Satish, you are correct

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. As @Satish says, the status you are talking about is "App Store Status". For example it will show "Ready for Sale" when this build is released.

See alse App Store Connect Help
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev18557d60e

[image]